# installing GEOS for shapely

Tags: python, shapely, geos

I am new to Shapely module . When i am trying to run the code in which i am trying to run shapely methods i am getting following error. It is trying to tell me that i should install GEOS version >=3.3 but in pip i am not able to find that version. So i am confused with this. any help will be much appreciated . Below is the exception which i am getting :

[image]

I have already install shapely with latest version.

Answer (score 2):

At best use a complete wheel package with GEOS included as provided by [gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely).